# How to find the integral $\int_0^z \exp(ax)x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1}dx$?

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

How to find the integral $\int_0^z \exp(ax)x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1}\text{d}x$ where $b,c\in \mathbb{C}, \Re(b)>0, \Re(c)>0$?

Comment: I'm not sure, but could you expand $(1-x)^{c-1}$ around $0$ as a series, then multiply it out by $x^{b-1}$ and then use some results from hypergeometric functions ?

Comment: the $z$ is annoying...i think what @Leucippus does is the best u can do here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ represent the desired integral. By expanding the exponential function then the integral leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{z} e^{a x} \, x^{b-1} \, (1-x)^{c-1} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{n}}{n!} \, \int_{0}^{z} x^{n+b-1} \, (1-x)^{c-1} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{n}}{n!} \, B_{z}(n+b, c)
\end{align}
where $B_{x}(a,b)$ is the [Incomplete Beta Function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17). By making use of the Incomplete Beta function properties it can be stated that
\begin{align}
I = B(b,c) \, {}_{1}F_{1}(b; b+c; a) - \frac{(1-z)^{c}}{c} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {}_{2}F_{1}(c, 1-b-n; c+1; 1-z) \, \frac{a^{n}}{n!}
\end{align}
where ${}_{1}F_{1}$ and ${}_{2}F_{1}$ are the confluent hypergeometric and hypergeometric functions, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^ze^{ax}x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1}~dx$

$=\int_0^1e^{azx}(zx)^{b-1}(1-zx)^{c-1}~d(zx)$

$=z^b\int_0^1e^{azx}x^{b-1}(1-zx)^{c-1}~dx$

$=\dfrac{z^b\Phi_1(b,1-c,b+1;z,az)}{b}$ (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series)